# What is doing this bitwise operation in order to emulate a RRC instruction

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, emulation, intel-8080

I'm working on a personal project to improve my knowledge on how a CPU works. So I'm doing a Intel 8080 emulator, which is a 8 bits microprocessor.

In the implementation of a RRC instruction, which [example](http://www.emulator101.com/logical-group.html) is this:

```
case 0x0f: {    
  uint8_t x = state->a;    
  state->a = ((x & 1) << 7) | (x >> 1);    
  state->cc.cy = (1 == (x&1));    
}
```

I can't understand how this line is working.

```
state->a = ((x & 1) << 7) | (x >> 1);
```

I know it's supposed to move all the bits to the right by 1 position, but I can't figure out how.

I would appreciate if someone could provide me an example of what it's actually doing step by step.

---

- `state->a` is a `uint8_t` which emulate the intel 8080 register named
  A.
- `0x0f` is the HEX value for RRC.
- The example has been provided by [this](http://www.emulator101.com) page.

Comment: How do you "know it's supposed to move all the bits to the right by 1 position"?

Comment: `(x >> 1)` - moving everything right. `((x & 1) << 7)` moving the rightmost bit to the leftmost position. cyclic shifting right over 8 bits.

Comment: The `x >> 1` shifts the (unsigned) quantity in `x` by one bit to the right, leaving a zero in the most significant bit.  The `(x & 1) << 7)` moves the least significant bit to the most significant bit (leaving zeros in the less significant bits).  The `|` combination of the two has achieved the RRC.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
@EugeneSh.
Thanks! Now I get it, the problem was that I didn't understand `(x & 1) << 7)`. If you want you can give a proper answer so I can vote it.

Comment: @EOF copy-pasting the intel 8080 manual definition of RRC "The contents of the accumulator are rotated one bit position to the right,with the low-order bit being transferred to the high-order bit position of the accumulator". Reading this now I see that it also provides an answer to my question, but I didn't understood it at first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets study the steps in order:

- `uint8_t x = state->a;` Use a temporary variable for the current value of the `A` register;
- `(x & 1) << 7` shift the low order bit to the high order bit; `(x & 1)` is the value of the low order bit as all other bits of `x` are masked off.
- `(x >> 1)` shift the other bits one place to the right (towards the lower bits).
- `state->a = ((x & 1) << 7) | (x >> 1);` combine the bits from the previous 2 steps and store as the new value of the `A` register;
- `state->cc.cy = (1 == (x&1));` store the low order bit from the original value into the carry bit (this is the bit that was rotated into the high order bit).

The effect of these steps is a rotation of the 8 bits one step to the right, with the low order bit landing into the carry flag. The [8080 reference card](http://fms.komkon.org/comp/CPUs/8080.txt) describes this as `Rotate Accumulator Right thru Carry`.

Note that the steps can be simplified:

- `state->a = ((x & 1) << 7) | (x >> 1);` is the same as `state->a = (x << 7) | (x >> 1);` because `state->a` is a `uint8_t`.
- `state->cc.cy = (1 == (x&1))` is the same as `state->cc.cy = x & 1;`

Comment: The problematic point for the OP is the second one. It is missing the "mask out everything but the rightmost bit". BTW, I don't see why it is done at all when working with 8-bit variable...

Comment: Thanks for the explication! actually it was the second point the one I didn't understand, and the link will help me with future instructions

Comment: Interesting — the http://www.emulator101.com site that the OP refers to has both RRC and RAR.  The RAR code copies the carry bit to the MSB instead of the MSB.  I'd wondered why the RRC code adjusted the carry bit, but it is clearer if the LSB is copied to the carry bit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm puzzled too: the implementation at emulator101.com is consistent with the documentation I linked, but seem inconsistent with the mnemonics: `RRC`, *Rotate Accumulator Right thru Carry* and `RAR` *Rotate Accumulator Right*.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I got it: the card is incorrect and the mnemonics are poorly chosen. The original documentation by intel [ http://altairclone.com/downloads/manuals/8080%20Programmers%20Manual.pdf ] has this description: *RLC               Rotate Accumulator Left.
RRC               Rotate Accumulator Right.
RAL               Rotate Accumulator Left through Carry.
RAR               Rotate Accumulator Right through Carry.*